# Postfix mailbox_transport and mailbox_command

Tags: configuration, postfix

I have Postfix set up in `main.cf` to use `mailbox_transport=lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp` as LDA, which works fine.

I also need to enable `mailbox_command` in order to pass internal sanity checks as Virtualmin expects in its configuration check to find a valid `mailbox_command` parameter.

The Postfix [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mailbox_transport) says

> The precedence of local(8) delivery features from high to low is:
>   aliases, .forward files, mailbox_transport_maps, mailbox_transport,
>   mailbox_command_maps, mailbox_command, home_mailbox,
>   mail_spool_directory, fallback_transport_maps, fallback_transport and
>   luser_relay.

For me this sounds as it would be of no harm to uncomment the `mailbox_command` line in order to satisfy the internal sanity checks while keeping the LMTP functionality in full working order.

Are there any known side effects?